# How to integrate Google charts as an AngularJs directive?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

There are some examples of integrating Google charts as an AngularJs directive.

Like this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/YzwjuU?p=preview

**Update**: I want to avoid waiting on google charts to be ready before bootstrapping the whole application (as shown in the example above):

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
    });
```

Is there a way to do this in a single module and not on the whole app?

**Update 2:** I have created my plunker and it works without waiting for the callback but I'm not sure if it will work in all cases.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7UUfcq4dD7nd4MylB4ni

Comment: Are you asking how to bootstrap Angular when the page loads instead of waiting for the chart callback to do it?  Also, I don't understand what you mean by limiting the charts dependency.  You can put some of the charting code into an Angular service, then just use a directive for the DOM manipulation part -- i.e., the last two lines of the link function in the plunkr you reference.

Comment: I agree I didn't construct my question properly. I will update.

Comment: What part are you concerned about not working?

Comment: I am concerned if chart will be available (every time) at the moment I am creating it in my directive. How come it works without waiting for setOnLoadCallback handler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you already figured out, you can initialize angular in the html or body tag, without waiting for google charts.

To ensure you don't try to render a chart before the google chart JavaScript code is ready,
I would have the directive $watch a new controller $scope property/flag that you set inside the callback function for google.setOnLoadCallback.  Inside the $watch callback, check to ensure the flag is set, then do your initialization.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good example of a **[AngularJs Google Chart Tools directive](http://jessemon.blogspot.com/2013/09/angular-google-chart-example.html)** in action.

- [Example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3RJ2HS?p=info).

### Instructions

These same instructions are in the plunker itself.

1. [Download ng-google-chart.js from github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/master/ng-google-chart.js) and add a script tag to your html.
2. Create a div like:

   `<div google-chart chart="chart" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}">
    </div>`
3. Add 'googlechart' to your module like this:

   `angular.module('myApp',[ 'googlechart', ...`
4. Populate the `$scope.chart` like this:

```js
{
  "type": "ColumnChart",
  "cssStyle": "height:200px; width:300px;",
  "data": {
    "cols": [
      {
        "id": "month",
        "label": "Month",
        "type": "string",
        "p": {}
      },
      {
        "id": "laptop-id",
        "label": "Laptop",
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
      },
      {
        "id": "desktop-id",
        "label": "Desktop",
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
      },
      {
        "id": "server-id",
        "label": "Server",
        "type": "number",
        "p": {}
      },
      {
        "id": "cost-id",
        "label": "Shipping",
        "type": "number"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "January"
          },
          {
            "v": 19,
            "f": "42 items"
          },
          {
            "v": 12,
            "f": "Ony 12 items"
          },
          {
            "v": 7,
            "f": "7 servers"
          },
          {
            "v": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "February"
          },
          {
            "v": 13
          },
          {
            "v": 1,
            "f": "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
          },
          {
            "v": 12
          },
          {
            "v": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "March"
          },
          {
            "v": 24
          },
          {
            "v": 0
          },
          {
            "v": 11
          },
          {
            "v": 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {
    "title": "Sales per month",
    "isStacked": "true",
    "fill": 20,
    "displayExactValues": true,
    "vAxis": {
      "title": "Sales unit",
      "gridlines": {
        "count": 6
      }
    },
    "hAxis": {
      "title": "Date"
    }
  },
  "formatters": {},
  "displayed": true
}
```

Comment: And how do you use google.visualization.DataTable with that? I could not find any useful example yet .

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe you could click **Ask a Question**.  Someone else might know.

Comment: Sorry but your Example Plunker doesn't display any graph

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @FtheBuilder.  I fixed the plunk.  It had a script include from github and the url changed, so I'm grabbing the script from cdnjs now.  One thing to note, that this is an old version of Angular which has a version 2 now.

Comment: Worked fine but I have that it returns the error google not defined when I load it on another view and then go to the view (ui router) where the charts is supposed to be loaded. Works fine when I refresh the page. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: @JohnAndrews sorry I have not worked with this in a long time.  You could try asking as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

There is Github project that wraps Google Charts into AngularJS directive

https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart

http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."

Answer (score 2):

I was having periodic trouble in Angular with the google chart API not being loaded on time to receive the data from a $http fetch.  The data came **first** sometimes (not always), and then the usage of it in the callback would fail with "google.visualization.DataTable is not a function"

Inside the callback returning data:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
```

To solve it, I found in ng-google-chart.js that there was a promise called "googleChartApiPromise", so I injected it, and wrapped the refresh call in it:

```
googleChartApiPromise.then(function() {
    refreshCharts();
});
```

This seems to solve the problem.