# How to draw charts as directives in angularjs and google-charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

How do I draw google-charts as directives?
I'm new in angular and I have saw a lot of questions about this topic, but all of them has more than 3 years, and i'm think there are used another angular version, because the use of this code:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
});
```

[Example of question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375728/how-to-integrate-google-charts-as-an-angularjs-directive)

And in my angular version this isn't reconized as a function.
But, what is exactly my problem ?

I don't like to use the angular-google-charts because i need to see what i'm doing.

I did my angular directive:

```
planejeinsumos.directive('card', function() {
return {
restrict: 'E',
template: 
    '<div class="card">' +
        '<div class="view overlay hm-white-slight" id=
{{obj.identificador}}></div>' +
        '<div class="card-block">' +
            '<h4 class="card-title">{{obj.nome}}</h4>' +
            '<p class="card-text">{{obj.descricao}}</p>' +
            '<div class="read-more">' +
                '<a href="#!" class="btn btn-brown">Comprar - 
{{obj.valor}} $</a>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>',
replace: true,

link: function(scope, elem, attr){

    console.log(2);
    var drawchart = function(obj){

        var chart = new 
google.visualization.ColumnChart($(obj.identificador));
        var options = {
            chartArea: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
            bars: 'vertical',
            hAxis: {
                minValue: 0
            },
            legend: { position: "none" }
        };
        var colunas = [
            ["", "Preço por Kg"],
            ["Marca A", 12.50],
            ["Marca B", 10.75],
            ["Marca C", 9.20],
            ["Marca D", 18.00]
        ];

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(colunas);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart(scope.obj));
     }
  }
});
```

And when i start the application I have two differents errors:

Mostly of times:
[Cannot read property ColumnChart of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHpDt.png)

Sometimes when I refresh the page:
[google.visualization.ColumnChart is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqp9W.png)

I started the google-charts in the end of index file:

```
    <script>
    console.log(0);
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    console.log(1);
    </script>
```

And i'm trying to make this directive independent (if i write the 'card' directive I draw a google chart in my page).

Thanks until now, and sorry about my english :)

**Final Solution**

The link parameter inside the directive became to:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr){

    var drawchart = function(){

        var insumo = scope.obj;
        var doc = document.getElementById(insumo.identificador);
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(doc);
        var options = {
            chartArea: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
            bars: 'vertical',
            hAxis: {
                minValue: 0
            },
            legend: { position: "none" }
        };
        var colunas = [
            ["", "Preço por Kg"],
            ["Marca A", 12.50],
            ["Marca B", 10.75],
            ["Marca C", 9.20],
            ["Marca D", 18.00]
        ];

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(colunas);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['corechart', 'bar'],
        callback: drawchart
    });
}
```

Thanks for all guys :)

Comment: The callback needs to finish before trying to draw a chart -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32459785/5090771) for more on loading google charts...

Comment: I removed the loader from index and changed **google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart(scope.obj))** to **google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar'], callback: drawchart(scope.obj)})** inside de directive and was the same errors.

Comment: the callback takes a reference to a function, you can't pass arguments as in the comment, you're passing the result of a function

Comment: It's work. So my main problem was because I was trying to draw the chart before the api is loaded?